# Is it better to use pointers for member class/object variables?

Tags: c++

When I am trying to keep a clean header file with regard to #includes, I find that I can do a better job by making all my members pointers to classes/objects that require inclusion of other header files because this way I can use forward declarations instead of #includes.

But I am starting to wonder if this is a good rule-of-thumb or not.

So for example take the following class - option 1:

```
class QAudioDeviceInfo;
class QAudioInput;
class QIODevice;

class QAudioRx
{
public:
    QAudioRx();
private:  
    QAudioDeviceInfo *mp_audioDeviceInfo;
    QAudioInput *mp_audioInput;
    QIODevice *mp_inputDevice;
};
```

However this can be re-written like this - option 2:

```
#include "QAudioDeviceInfo.h"
#include "QAudioInput.h"
#include "QIODevice.h"

class QAudioRx
{
public:
    QAudioRx();
private:  
    QAudioDeviceInfo m_audioDeviceInfo;
    QAudioInput m_audioInput;
    QIODevice m_inputDevice;
};
```

Option 1, is generally my preference because its a nicer cleaner header to include. However option 2 does not require dynamic allocation / de-allocation of resources.

Maybe this could be seen as a subjective/opinion-based question (and I know the opinion-police will be all over this), so lets avoid "I like" and "I prefer" and stick to facts/key-points.

So my question is, in general, what is the best practice (if there is one) and why? Or if there is not one best practice (normally the case) when is it good to use each one?

**edit**

Sorry, this was really meant for private variables - not public ones.

Comment: `However this can be re-written like this` It cannot be rewritten since option 2 is not equivalent to option 1. These are different structures that may serve different purposes. There is nothing to choose between, it depends on what you need at the moment. And you definitely should not design structures based on how clean (or not) header inclusion is.

Comment: @freakish ok fair point, but you could implement it either way if you are going to instantiate the members once and only once.

Comment: Having the layout of an instance so heavily affected by external considerations such as headers maintenability makes me slightly nervous.

Comment: @code_fodder Yes, then you have to ask yourself: which structure serves my purposes better? Which is easier to control? Which one do I need? Again: header inclusion should have nothing to do with class design.

Comment: @perencia - why is that?, I mean can you explain a little more? thanks

Comment: @freakish ok, thanks I take your point : ) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trade-off between compilation time and compile-time dependencies (which usually correlates with the number of include files needed) and simplicity and efficiency.

Option 1 will compile faster, but almost certainly run slower. Every time you access a member variable there is an indirection through a pointer, and the objects that the pointers refer to must be allocated and managed separately. If the allocation is dynamic then that has an extra cost, and the additional logic to manage the separate objects risks introducing bugs. For a start you have raw pointers, so you must define (or delete) a copy constructor, copy assignment, and probably destructor, and maybe move constructor and move assignment (your example is missing all of those, and so is probably horribly broken).

Option 2 requires some additional includes, and so everything that uses `QAudioRx` needs to be recompiled when any of those headers change. That tightly couples `QAudioRx` to those other types. In a large project that can be significant (but in a small one it probably doesn't matter - if the time to build your whole project is measured in seconds then it's certainly not worth it!)

However I would say your option 1 is almost never a good idea. If you care about reducing dependencies and build times then use the [pImpl idiom](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) (see also [pimpl-idiom](/questions/tagged/pimpl-idiom) for related questions) instead:

```
class QAudioRx
{
public:
    QAudioRx();

private:  
    class QAudioRxImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<QAudioRxImpl> m_impl;
};
```

(N.B. My use of `std::unique_ptr<QAudioRx>` assumes the impl object will be dynamically allocated, because that's the most common approach, the solution can be adjusted if the object is managed differently).

Now all the member variables are part of the "impl" object, which is not defined in the header. This means that access to the members from within the impl class is direct, not through pointers, but access from the `QAudioRx` must perform one indirection to call a function on the impl class.

This still reduces dependencies, but makes it simpler to manage the extra complexity because there are no raw pointers so the special member functions will do something sensible automatically. By default it will be movable, but not copyable, and will clean up in the destructor.

Answer (score 5):

Use pointers if you need pointers. Pointers are not for avoiding includes. Includes are not evil. When you need to use them, use them. Simple rules equal happy programming!

Using pointers in your case will bring a lot of unnecessary overhead. You **may** have to allocate your object dynamically which is not a good choice for your case. You have also to deal with memory management manually. Simply, there is no reason to use pointers here unless your case demand that (for example you want the object to live more than the pointer itself (non-ownership pattern for example).

Comment: +1, yeah its true, this is why I am starting to ask questions about how I am going about this. Its good to get a someone to nudge you back on course - thanks : )

Comment: Using pointers does not mean you have to allocate objects on "the heap". That is a strange notion I often see repeated here.

Comment: @juanchopanza True. But how it would be allocated in stack with respect to scopes ?\

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you explain a little further? - if you need to allocate memory for the pointer where else can you allocate it?

Comment: @code_fodder You can allocate it on the stack, or statically, or indirectly on the free store via something else that creates and stores object in a container. There is an open ended number of options.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK I got you

Comment: @code_fodder What you will have to consider is object ownership. Who owns the object pointer at by the pointers? When you store values, the ownership is clear. With pointers, you have to decide and then make sure it is clear.

Comment: @juanchopanza it's true, you don't need to make a heap allocation to fill a pointer, anyway I think this is not what we usually do in the case the question exposes.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi "Heap" is an implementation detail. What you really mean is that "dynamic memory allocation" will be needed. _Where_ that memory lives is not really relevant, be it a heap, pre-reserved static memory or elsewhere. _"... there is no reason to use pointers here."_ is factually an incorrect statement. The lifetimes might just not coincide with that of the owner class. Feel free to edit your answer. I'll hold on to voting a bit longer :-)

Comment: Also, sometimes, when using templates heavily, there could be an issue with compilation times if we decide not to use pointers..

Answer (score 1):

When you are working on small project where number of class are little then you should go with option 2.

But when you are working with very large project in which number of classes are very large and compilation time of project is one of criteria for developing architecture of your project then go with option 1.

In most of cases option 1 is just fine. In real world application you need to combine both of this option choose trade of between compilation time and pretty look of your code(without pointers and nacked new(dynamic allocation) for objects.)